# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')

Tags: reactjs

If the function is in a component, then everything works fine.
if I take it out separately and export it to a component, then I get an error **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')**

```
const getAverageScores = (data) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, {value}) => acc + value, 0) / data.length;
```

}

Help me please

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data.length) {
         setAverage(getAverageScores(data))
    }
}, [data])
```

and I use getAverageScores there

```
export  const getStandardDeviation = (data) => {
const total = 0;
const averageScore = getAverageScores()
const squaredDeviations = data.reduce((total, data) => {
    const deviation = data && data.value - averageScore;
    const deviationSquared = deviation * deviation;

    return total + deviationSquared;
}, total);

return Math.sqrt(squaredDeviations / data.length);
```

}

Comment: how do you use `getAverageScores`?

Comment: is that the only usage of that function? getAverageScores's getting `undefined` as value. Check `data`

Comment: I use it there` import {getAverageScores} from "./average";

export  const getStandardDeviation = (data) => {
    const total = 0;
    const averageScore = getAverageScores()
    const squaredDeviations = data.reduce((total, data) => {
        const deviation = data && data.value - averageScore;
        const deviationSquared = deviation * deviation;

        return total + deviationSquared;
    }, total);

    return Math.sqrt(squaredDeviations / data.length);
}`

Comment: `const averageScore = getAverageScores()` -> no args are passed to it. Change it to `const averageScore = getAverageScores(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `getAverageScores` with `undefined`.

```
const averageScore = getAverageScores()
```

should be

```
const averageScore = getAverageScores(data)
```